# System crash after some idle time: Juno

Tags: release-juno, crash

I was working normally, had to go for a couple of hours. Left the system on, downloading an ISO in Opera,  and a couple of more apps opened. When I came back, a black screen with a big cursor was on the top, blinking... Seems mouse and keyboard responded, as HD reacted typing some keys, yet, screen all black. Had to turn off the computer.
I just installed Elementary for the first time in my PC, trying Juno

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What settings do you have set under "power" in settings? 
I have had some weird reboots happening when the system should have just suspended or even locked. I ended up setting everything to never.

I also ran a command to keep the eOS from ever going into suspended mode. Because in my case that was what caused random reboots.

Comment: Thank you; I configured the OS as per your recommendations.